# Batch processing in mqtt

Tags: mqtt, batch-processing, message-queue, publish-subscribe

Is it possible to use batch processing in mqtt protocol.
Instead of reading and processing message by message, can we process a group of messages together in mqtt?

Answer (score 1):

No, the MQTT protocol has no support for batching messages